# asp.net right month under right tab

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is my code / view right now.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="portlet-body form">
    <div class="form-group">
        @foreach (var date in ViewBag.MissingDays)
        {
            var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
                @date.ToString("ddd").Substring(0, 2)
                @isoDate
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And now it would print out each date like this: "Mo yymmdd tu yymmdd we yymmdd"
But what I want to do is I want to so all dates that belongs to may would go under the may tab, all dates under october would go under october etc.

It's a bit messy right now.[image]

So what I want to try to make is to have it something along these lines, It want it to say May, and all the dates that are missing in may will be under that section, and so on.

This is how i get my missing days from the database (It's my databaselayer)

```
        public List<DateTime> GetConsultantMissingDays(Guid consultantId)
    {
        //List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(-3);
        var dates = db.TimeReports.Where(x => x.FK_ConsultantID == consultantId && x.Date >= oldDate).Select(x => x.Date);
        //db.

        return Constants.WorkDays.Except(dates).ToList();
    }
```

And this is how I get the dates to the Viewbag.MissingDays(My Controller)

```
var missingdays = new DatabaseLayer().GetConsultantMissingDays(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
        if (missingdays.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewData["missingDays"] = "";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.MissingDays = missingdays;
        }

        ViewData.Model = projectData;

        return View();
```

Comment: Is `date` a `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes, it's a datetime.

Comment: You can check my answer.

Comment: @Kamo Yes, but I can't group by month because it dosen't not exist.

Comment: Why you are passing `ViewData["missingDays"] = "";` instead of empty collection in `ViewBag.MissingDays = missingdays;` when `missingdays.Count == 0`?

Comment: @Kamo Because that's how I thought I would do it, so I did. I can always change it up.

Comment: Ok casting operating was missing. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot check exact HTML layout right now but I can give you a hint ;)

You should group your dates by month and then iterate over groups items:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="portlet-body form">
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach(var @group in ((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.MissingDays).GroupBy(x => x.Month))
    {
        <div class="col-md-2">
        foreach (var date in @group)
        {
            var isoDate = date.ToString("yyMMdd");
                 <input type="checkbox" id="isoDate" name="isoDate" value="@isoDate" />
                 @date.ToString("ddd").Substring(0, 2)
                 @isoDate
        }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

You can add then some column header to determine proper month.

EDIT: According to the @SimonGates comment - take into consideration that above solution is not taking into consideration various years. In case there are different years, grouping operation should be extended.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this groups together the month irrespective of the Year which may not be the desired result. E.g  Jan 2014 & Jan 2015 would be grouped together, of course this may not be an issue if MissingDays never spans across years but though worth pointing out for the OP.

Comment: @Kamo Ah, I see! I can award the bounty in 23 hours